# c# generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, message-queue

I have a method that receives messages from a queue of msmq.

I have 6 different queues in msmq and i d like a single generic method that would receive the messages. THis work, but i need to write 6 methods for each queue. I d like to make it more generic.

```
public List<QueMessage> getMessagesFromObj1Queue()
{
    List<QueMessage> messageList = new List<QueMessage>();

    QueObj1 que = new QueObj1();

    while (que.ReceiveAll().Count > 0)
    {
        varmessage = que.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        messageList.Add(message);
    }

    return messageList;
}
```

I have 5 different object which just extends a single abstract class. Below doenst work.

```
public List<QueMessage> getMessagesFromObj1Queue<T>(T que)
{
    List<QueMessage> messageList = new List<QueMessage>();

    while (que.ReceiveAll().Count > 0)
    {
        varmessage = que.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        messageList.Add(message);
    }

    return messageList;
}
```

Above doesnt work

how to fix this?

Comment: You are far more likely to get an answer if you post the actual error messages you receive, instead of just saying "doesn't work". *What* doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If `T` in your example is some base class that all queue objects inherit,** then you can just pass that to the method instead of `T`:

```
public List<QueMessage> getMessagesFromObj1Queue<T>(QueueObjBase que) { ... }
```

Otherwise, if there's come common interface that all `T`'s will implement, use that as a generic constraint:

```
public List<QueMessage> getMessagesFromObj1Queue<T>(T que) 
   where T : [yourInterface]
{
}
```

Without a generic constraint on `T`, the compiler doesn't have any information to know what method or properties are available, and so can only treat `T` as `object` - which, of course, doesn't have a `RecieveAll()` method.

Comment: I dont have interface but a single abstract class.

Comment: If that's the case, then just pass that abstract type to the method directly. I assume that `ReceiveAll()` already returns instances of `QueMessage`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you've told the C# compiler nothing about the type of `que` and hence it must treat it as an object.  You must provide more information so that it can properly bind the Receive method.

This can be done by adding a generic constraint to the method.  For example

```
public List<QueMessage> getMessagesFromObj1Queue<T>(T que) 
  where T : [InsertBaseTypeOfQues]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a where contraint onto the method and delcare the type param to be your base class.

> where T : 
>    The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

see [generic type constrains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(VS.80).aspx) from msdn

Answer (score 1):

As it is, the type T has no ReceiveAll method. You need to add a constraint, so that the compiler knows that the method exists, for any instantiation of T. So, you'd get:

public List getMessagesFromObj1Queue(T que) : where T : XXX

I don't know MSMQ enough to know what XXX should be, though.